# Spring boot application with GraphQL runs but cannot build package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql, grpc

I'm working with Spring Boot, GraphQL, and gRPC in my project. I’ve been testing the app by running it, and it has been working fine. However, when I tried to build it using `mvn package` to generate gRPC classes, it give me a bunch of errors as follows:

```html
2018-10-24 16:14:30.454  INFO 67640 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/graphiql]}" onto public void com.oembedler.moon.graphiql.boot.GraphiQLController.graphiql(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException
2018-10-24 16:14:30.492  INFO 67640 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-10-24 16:14:30.492  INFO 67640 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-10-24 16:14:30.537  INFO 67640 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException: Error while instrumenting class rakuten/travel/orchestrationapi/models/DashboardInfoMethodAccess.
 at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_8ff85ea.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:93)
 at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
 at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.AccessClassLoader.defineClass(AccessClassLoader.java:98)
 at com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.MethodAccess.get(MethodAccess.java:275)
 at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.MethodFieldResolverDataFetcher.<init>(MethodFieldResolver.kt:126)
 at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.MethodFieldResolver.createDataFetcher(MethodFieldResolver.kt:93)
 at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser$createObject$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.apply(SchemaParser.kt:124)
 at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser$createObject$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.apply(SchemaParser.kt:46)
 at graphql.schema.GraphQLObjectType$Builder.field(GraphQLObjectType.java:163)
 at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser.createObject(SchemaParser.kt:122)
 at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser.parseSchemaObjects(SchemaParser.kt:83)
 at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser.makeExecutableSchema(SchemaParser.kt:107)
 at com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.graphQLSchema(GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.java:87)
 at com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a850164c.CGLIB$graphQLSchema$1(<generated>)
 at com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a850164c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a399cb3e.invoke(<generated>)
 at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
 at com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a850164c.graphQLSchema(<generated>)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
 at 

….

org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
 at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
 at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
 at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
 at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error while instrumenting class /orchestrationapi/resolvers/QueryMethodAccess.
 at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_8ff85ea.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrumentError(Instrumenter.java:166)
 at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_8ff85ea.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:117)
 at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_8ff85ea.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:91)
 ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
2018-10-24 16:14:31.979  INFO 67640 --- [           main] r.t.o.OrchestrationApiApplicationTests   : Started OrchestrationApiApplicationTests in 4.559 seconds (JVM running for 5.935)
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.839 sec - in rakuten.travel.orchestrationapi.OrchestrationApiApplicationTests
2018-10-24 16:14:32.048  INFO 67640 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@3220c28: startup date [Wed Oct 24 16:14:27 JST 2018]; root of context hierarchy

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

(I had to cut some of the errors because of the character limit)

As you can see, it still says `Failures : 0` and the build is success in the end. However, the classes I need for gRPC are not generated. I'm using `graphql-java-tools` for GraphQL.

Any idea how to solve this problem? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?